# Organising TFS over multiple projects

Tags: tfs

I have inherited a TFS 2017 on-premise. It has 1 collection which contains 10 projects.  Each project has its own work items, builds, source code and produces a separate application/website.  This all makes sense from a developer perspective as all the software is independent and builds/releases separately.  Each new 'business project' however does tend to span multiple 'TFS projects' in order to deliver the features needed.

How is it best to organise this from a management perspective? 
Options:
1) Create a 'Management' project that has no code or work items but just has dashboards and queries.
2) Put all the code into one project.
3) Create a 'Epic TFS project' that just contained Epics - with PBIs in the relevant TFS project.
4) Secret option 4 that I don't know about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use one team project with multiple teams underneath.

Your current structure is like this:

- Team Project Collection

  - Project 1
  - Project 2
  - Project N

The structure you're after is this:

- Team Project Collection

  - Project A

    - Team A

      - Team 1 (corresponds to Project 1)
      - Team 2
      - Team 3

Basically, each Team is assigned to a separate area path. You can use the hierarchy of area paths to subdivide everything so that it can be rolled up and easily reported. In the example above, you can report on Team A (which rolls up Team 1, 2, 3), or on each of the Teams individually.

Each team can have its own separate subareas, iterations, etc. But all source code, builds, and so on live within the same team project. Access to those entities can be controlled via security groups.

Now, the question of "How do I go from the current structure to the new structure?" is a much bigger problem. There's no easy way to combine multiple team projects.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Why do you recommend this over having a separate management project for reporting?  What would be the main advantages/disadvantages of this approach?

Comment: @simon831 The [docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/projects/about-projects?view=azure-devops#when-to-add-another-project) say:

In general, we recommend that you use a single project to support your organization or enterprise. A single project minimizes the maintenance of administrative tasks and supports the most optimized / full-flexibility cross-link object experience.

Even if you have many teams working on hundreds of different applications and software projects, you can most easily manage them within a single project. A project serves to isolate [...]